# POST request works with curl and Postman, but fails with javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I'm having this problem. I'm trying to fetch a POST request with javascript, but what I receive back is a 415 error:

```
const getToken = async () => {
const response = await fetch('https://thebetter.bsgroup.eu/authorization/signIn', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    },
    body: {},
});
const data = response.json();
console.log(data);
```

};

With the below curl command I get the correct response. Same with Postman.

```
curl -X POST "https://thebetter.bsgroup.eu/Authorization/SignIn" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}"
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you clarify what the error is? 415 can be broad. Wrap your fetch in a `try/catch` block and note the error in the catch statement

Comment: the error is:
main.js:3 POST https://thebetter.bsgroup.eu/authorization/signIn net::ERR_ABORTED 415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `mode: 'no-cors'`.

For no-cors you can only perform this application-types posts:

- `text/plain`
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data`

Since you are trying to perform `application/json`the browser is overwriting to `text/plain`.

Do you have access to the server from `thebetter.bsgroup.eu`? If so, just remove the `mode: no-cors` from the request and add the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': [REQUEST'S-HOST].com` to the response. Otherwise, you can't perform this operation due to security concerns.